# Is there a definition of morphism of gluing data of schemes that makes gluing an adjoint functor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, adjoint-functors

[Tag 01JA](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JA) of the Stacks Project is about gluing schemes. There, a gluing data is defined as a collection of schemes, and isomorphisms between open subsets of those schemes satisfying the cocycle relation. Such a gluing data can be glued to a scheme which I will denote $glue(X)$

The description for the set of morphisms from $glue(X)$ to $Y$ seems like some kind of adjoint functor/universal property. However without a notion of morphism of gluing data, we don't have a category of gluing data.

My question is: is there a way to define morphisms of gluing data so that $glue(X)$ is a functor that has an adjoint?

Comment: What ideas do you have?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are gluing data, a morphism might be a collection of morphisms from a scheme in $X$ to a scheme in $Y$ that commute with the isomorphisms. However the image a morphism in the collection doesn't need to be contained inside a scheme in $Y$, so I don't think this would work.

Comment: The gluing datum is a diagram in the category of schemes. The glued scheme is its colimit. The category of gluing datum is the category of diagrams of a given shape. The universal property (that came from the definition of colimit) can be described by the adjunction of the limit functor with the diagonal diagram functor.

Comment: @Yesterday was dramatic Thank you! can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it.